# Comparacion de nombres en Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de la universidad, que es ingresar nombres en un Array(vector), la cuestion es que no puedo ingresar el mismo nombre mas de dos veces, ejemplo: estudiante 1. Juan / estudiante 2. Juan, me pueden ayudar por favor.

```
System.out.println("Por favor, ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes: ");
int cantidadEstudiante = sc.nextInt();
acumuladorCantidadEstudiantes += 1;
String nombresEstudiante [] = new String [cantidadEstudiante];

for(int k = 0 ; k < cantidadEstudiante ; k++) { // Inicio FOR.
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.print("Estudiante: "+(k+1)+" \nNombre: ");
  nombresEstudiante[k] = sc.next();
  /*if(nombresEstudiante.equalsIgnoreCase(nombresEstudiante)) {
      System.out.println("Ingreselo de nuevo");
  }*/
} // Fin FOR.
```

Comment: Tu código es correcto, ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: No me tira ningun error, solo digamos si yo pongo dos veces Juan lo asigna al vector y muestra las dos veces Juan, quiero evitar eso, si alguien escribe dos veces el mismo nombre que no lo deje.

Answer (score 1):

Con un método que compruebe que no exista el nombre ingresado en el array puedes resolver el problema:

```
for (int k = 0; k < cantidadEstudiante; k++) { // Inicio FOR.
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Estudiante: " + (k + 1) + " \nNombre: ");

    String tmp = sc.next();
    if(!exists(nombresEstudiante,tmp)){
        nombresEstudiante[k] = tmp;
    }else{
        k--;
    }
} // Fin FOR.
```

.

```
public static boolean exists(String[] arr, String tmp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (tmp.equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes verificar en la lista si ya existe el nombre recoriendolo.

```
System.out.println("Por favor, ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes: ");
int cantidadEstudiante = sc.nextInt();
String nombresEstudiante [] = new String [cantidadEstudiante];
int contador=0;
    //Ya que puede existir nombres descartados se debe pedir otro nombre hasta llenar la lista
    do{
        boolean esEstudiante=false;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Estudiante: "+(contador+1)+" \nNombre: ");
        String nombre=sc.next();
        //Verifica que el nombre se encuentra en la lista de alumnos
        for(int i=0;i<nombresEstudiante.length;i++){
            if(nombre.equals(nombresEstudiante[i])){
                //Si existe el nombre lo descarta y sale del for
                esEstudiante=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(esEstudiante){
            System.out.println("El nombre: "+nombre+" ya fue ingresado anteriormente ingreso otro");
        }else{
            nombresEstudiante[contador]=nombre;
            contador++;
        }

    }while(contador<cantidadEstudiante);

    System.out.print("Lista de Estudiantes");
    for(int i=0;i<cantidadEstudiante;i++){
        System.out.println(nombresEstudiante[i]);
    }
```